# Oracle SQL query: how to use count

Tags: sql, oracle

I have data in following format

```
userid  amount  term  APR
1        10       5    1
1        10       4    2
2        20       6    1
2        20       4    3
2        20       3    1
```

I want to do order by on amount, term, APR so in output I want maximum amount and it's corresponding term, APR. In case amount is same, choose one with max term and same happens if term is also same. but combination of these three is always unique.

output columns:

```
userid,  amount, term, apr, numberOfRowsForEachUser
  1       10       5   1      2
  2       20       6   1      3
```

**Question: I am able to get first four columns, but not sure how to get 'total no of offers' or 'total number of rows per user'.**

My query looks like this.

```
select 
  userid,amount,term,apr
  from 
( select userid, amount, term,  apr
   RANK() OVER (PARTITION BY userid ORDER BY amount,term,apr) amount_rank,   
from 
   tableXYZ
) 
where amount_rank = 1
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Just add a `COUNT(*)` analytic function

```
select 
  userid,amount,term,apr, cnt
  from 
( select userid, amount, term,  apr
   RANK() OVER (PARTITION BY userid ORDER BY amount,term,apr) amount_rank,   
   COUNT(*) OVER (PARTITION BY userid) cnt
from 
   tableXYZ
) 
where amount_rank = 1
```

Answer (score 2):

I liked Justing answer (+1) but still wanted to provide an alternative answer which is more intuitive to me:

```
select x.userid,x.amount,x.term,x.apr,y.cnt
from tableXYZ x, (select userid, COUNT(1) cnt from tableXYZ group by userid) y
where x.term = (select max(term) from tableXYZ xx where xx.userid = x.userid)
and x.userid = y.userid
```

You can play with it [here](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/b6b4e/11)